# Ajax heavy page techinques using jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance

I have an Ajax heavy webpage, that is to say a page where the user rarely refreshes but all changes to a group of inputs on the page are saved to the database via AJAX every 30 seconds and other AJAX calls can add inputs (and other HTML) to the DOM.
To save unnecessary database entries, each group of inputs is only given an ID once something has been entered and is therefore in the database - before this, the group as the ID of 0 and once something has been entered, the AJAX call updates this ID to that of the database entry.

This seems to work well when tested, but on an everyday scale and in lots of browsers etc it seems to fail (some problems include the IDs aren't correctly matched up with groups of inputs or information is duplicated etc).

My question is, would it better to use some sort of dedicated JS framework for this page instead of lots of AJAX requests etc? (I've googled this but cant see anything approriate) If not, does anyone have any suggestions for AJAX heavy pages?

Comment: why do u have to write in db every 30 sec? why don't you use localstorage for example or session vars to keep track of changes etc, and then when a timer expires for a field without changes or focus, save it to database. No need for extra id's.

Comment: Yep, hadn't thought of local storage (but what happens if they close their browser prematurely?), but once an input has an ID, it doesn't get a new one for every AJAX call (since it just updates the DB instead of inserting) if that makes sense?